# Permanent redirect on Ubuntu for Mosquitto bidirectional MQTT traffic

Tags: networking, iptables, redirect, nat

I need to permanently redirect all traffic in the short term from an old mosquitto server to a new one until the firmware updates have been completed on the edge devices. I tried using iptables as such according to some previous answers about redirection of traffic:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1883 -j DNAT --to-destination 41.185.48.194:1883
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9001 -j DNAT --to-destination 41.185.48.194:9001
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 41.185.48.194 --dport 9001 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 41.185.48.194 --dport 1883 -j MASQUERADE
```

But I get no traffic once the rules are in place.

Any help would be appreciated